# Unable to send text message to India (+91) using AWS SNS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-sns

This is what the CloudWatch response looks like

```
{
        "notification": {
            "messageId": "69f1ef66-3db1-5ed0-bbdf-b8b32c6dbe03",
            "timestamp": "2020-09-11 05:48:12.245"
        },
        "delivery": {
            "destination": "+91xxxxxxxxxx",
            "smsType": "Promotional",
            "providerResponse": "Internal Error",
            "dwellTimeMs": 41
        },
        "status": "FAILURE"
    }
```

I'm using the region ap-south-1 which is in the supported regions and using an Indian phone number (+91) but still getting this error. Apart from AWS CLI, I've also tried python boto3 library to send the message to no avail.This is the python code that I've tried:

```
import botot3
client = boto3.client('sns','ap-south-1')
client.publish(PhoneNumber='+91xxxxxxxxxx',Message='Hello')
```

Comment: Looks like something you would need to ask AWS Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe sending SMS messages to Indian phone numbers requires you to register a sender ID as India has stricter laws on texts.  Do you have a non-Indian phone number you can test with to confirm?

From [Supported Regions and Countries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html#sms-support-note-3):

> Senders are required to use a pre-registered alphabetic sender ID.
> Additional registration steps are required. For more information, see
> [Special requirements for sending SMS messages to recipients in India](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id-india.html).